# Why do so many things run in 'human observable time'?

Tags: complexity-theory, theory, computation-theory

I've studied complexity theory and I come from a solid programming background and it's always seemed odd that so many things seem to run in times that are intrinsic to humans. I'm wondering if anyone has any ideas as to why this is?

I'm generally speaking of times in the range of 1 second to 1 hour. If you consider how narrow that span of time is proportional the the billions of operations per second a computer can handle, it seems odd that such a large number of things fall into that category.

A few examples:

Encoding video: 20 minutes

Checking for updates: 5 seconds

Starting a computer: 45 seconds

You get the idea...

Don't you think most things should fall into one of two categories: instantaneous / millions of years?

Comment: This seems like a very subjective question

Comment: No, this is not a subjective question, this is off topic here, in SO.

Comment: It would be better suited if migrated...

Comment: mmm... why do so many things that we can observe fall in the category of things we can observe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that computers are tools, and tools are meant to be setup, used, and have their results analyzed by humans (mostly), it makes sense that the majority of operations would be created in a way that didn't take longer than the lifespan of a typical human.

I would argue that *most* single operations are effectively "instantaneous" (in that they run in less than perceptible time), but are rarely used as a single operation.  Humans are capable of creating complexity, and given that many computational operations intrinsically contain a balance between speed and some other factor (quality, memory usage, etc), it actually makes sense that many operations are designed in a way where that balance places them into a "times that are intrinsic to humans".  However, I'd personally word that as "a time that is assumed to be acceptable to a human user, given the result generated."

Answer (score 2):

probably because it signifies the cut-off where people consider further optimizations not being worth the effort.

and clearly, having a computer that takes millions of years to boot wouldn't be very useful (or maybe it would, but you just wouldn't know yet, because it's still booting :P )

Comment: well, it may give you the answer to life the universe and everything!